# jQuery/javascript show first tab by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code for a tab I am trying to create.

```
<style>
nav.tab {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
}
#static {
    margin-left: 200px;

}
/* Float the list items side by side*/ 
section.tab {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items*/ 
nav.tab a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
}

 /*Change background color of links on hover */
nav.tab a:hover {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
nav.tab a:focus, .active {
    background-color: white;
    color: purple;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-top: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 600px;
}
</style>

<nav class="tab">
  <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openSetting(event,'Profile')">Profile</a>
  <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openSetting(event, 'Password')">Password</a>
  <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openSetting(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a>
</nav>

<div id="static" class="container">
<div id="Profile" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Password" class="tabcontent">
  <h4 style="font-family: Segoe UI; color: purple; padding: 15px 0 15px 0;">Change Password</h4>
        <p id="label">Enter OLD Password</p><input type="password" id="field" size="25" name="oldpassword" required="required"><br/><br/>
        <p id="label">Enter NEW  Password</p><input type="password" id="field" size="25" name="newpassword" required="required"><br/><br/>
        <p id="label">Enter NEW Password AGAIN</p><input type="password" id="field" size="25" name="newpassword2" required="required"><br/><br/>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function openSetting(evt, settingName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    $('.tabcontent a:first').tab('show');
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(settingName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

I am trying to make the first tab show by default. 
As of now, when the page loads none of the content for the tabs can be seen because of a 'display: none;' css value. But i need the first page to show on load.

Help me out please.

Comment: The layout of your html/code is *really* distracting, and makes answering your question more work than it should be

Comment: include your css as well

Comment: @Jamiec i have edited the code, its now easier to view

Comment: @ThinkDifferent i have included the css

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need only to set class ".active" to the first tab.

```
<a href="#" class="tablinks active" onclick="openSetting(event,'Profile')">Profile</a>
```

And in js, when you handle click on tab do something like this:

```
$(nav.tab>a).removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use jqueryui? Tabs are included there.

also bootstrap provides nice tabs:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tab&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution --> https://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/

Also try make a new class, for example class selected, and manage the selected tab (also the default selected tab) with that class and then, with JS add or remove that class.

See also this --> http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content

See u!

Answer (score 0):

Just fire that function with the desired params on document.ready:

```
openSetting(event, 'Profile');
```

```js
openSetting(event, 'Profile');

function openSetting(evt, settingName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  //$('.tabcontent a:first').show();
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(settingName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
nav.tab {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}
#static {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
/* Float the list items side by side*/

section.tab {
  float: left;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items*/

nav.tab a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}
/*Change background color of links on hover */

nav.tab a:hover {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
/* Create an active/current tablink class */

nav.tab a:focus,
.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: purple;
}
/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-top: none;
  height: 700px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<nav class="tab">
  <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openSetting(event,'Profile')">Profile</a>
  <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openSetting(event, 'Password')">Password</a>
  <a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openSetting(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a>
</nav>

<div id="static" class="container">
  <div id="Profile" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Password" class="tabcontent">
    <h4 style="font-family: Segoe UI; color: purple; padding: 15px 0 15px 0;">Change Password</h4>
    <p id="label">Enter OLD Password</p>
    <input type="password" id="field" size="25" name="oldpassword" required="required">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p id="label">Enter NEW Password</p>
    <input type="password" id="field" size="25" name="newpassword" required="required">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p id="label">Enter NEW Password AGAIN</p>
    <input type="password" id="field" size="25" name="newpassword2" required="required">
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming first tab to be shown as the default tab.
These are the changes

Profile

add this line after closing bracket of function openSetting.

```
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```